# Is a smart switch needed to make a VLAN or can a router do it?

Tags: vlan, internet

Pretty much as the title says. From what I've read online it depends on the router, but looking for a bit of confirmation.

The main problem is that we need more devices connected to the internet than the client says they have IP addresses available instore for, so we are looking into configuring a VLAN for our devices. However our knowledge of networks is limited and we're looking for more information on this topic, but its hard to google for information when you don't know what it is you don't know about.

A bit of background info:

- I don't have any info about the network hardware or infrastructure.
- The environment is a store so I presume it is commercial grade hardware
- We would like to, if possible, avoid having to add a smart switch to their network
- We have no more details other than "We don't have enough IP addresses"

Any help on this would be much appreciated, as would explained criticisms of our idea and suggestions of better ideas.

Comment: What sort of equipment is there (make/model). A lot depends on the answer to that. Until you can provide the details which you say you don't have, it is pointless to ask this question. For instance, a router with multiple LAN interfaces or a built-in switch module may work with more than one non-managed switch for VLANs.

Comment: If I got it right, your (only) problem is that you have more Clients than free IP - Adresses, right?
Could you give us an example of such IP? Or is there any kind of IP - Adressing - Scheme available? Maybe all you need is a little subnetting combined with NAT...

Comment: Are you talking about public ip addresses or private?  Configuring vlans doesn't create more addresses, creating a larger network through sub netting will though.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are looking for plain old VLAN?

VLAN is the partioning of a bridge (usually a switch) into virtual pieces.
Usually a bridge/switch feature, yes.
Many modern high-end routers can have multiple bridge contexts, can break them into multiple VLANs, can do fancy manipulation of VLAN tagging, so on.

Can you be searching for VLAN tagging (IEEE 802.1q)? Look for information about 'router on a stick'. For instance: [router on a stick](http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/336-cisco-router-8021q-router-stick.html) It's a mechanism for aggregating multiple VLANs into a router.

Comment: They might be what I'm looking for, I will have a look and accept the answer if they are.

Comment: @Cob50nm Look for information about 'router on a stick'. For instance: http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/336-cisco-router-8021q-router-stick.html

Comment: A router-on-a-stick will need a managed switch for VLANs. You need to be able to configure the switch for the trunk port and assign VLANs to the various ports. It's a crap shoot whether or not non-managed switches will drop tagged frames, but they certainly don't understand VLANs.

Answer (score 1):

First some background:

The first thing to note is that there is a distinction between VLANs and subnets. A VLAN is a group of Ethernet devices that are isolated at layer 2 from other groups of Ethernet devices on the same physical infrastructure. A subnet is a block of IP addresses defined by the subnet mask where the devices within the block know they can reach each other without going via a gateway/router.

Often there is a one to one mapping between subnets and VLANs but there doesn't have to be. There are some caveats with running multiple subnets on the same VLAN but for the most part it's workable.

As a general rule if more than one VLAN needs to pass through a switch then that switch should support VLANs. IF a router is going to connect two VLANs on the same physical infrastructure then either the router needs to support VLANs or it needs to have a seperate connection to the switch for each VLAN.

---

There are several possible soloutions to "Not enough IPs" depending on what exactly the problem is, what equipment is present, how cooperative different stakeholders are and so-on.

1. Run a new subnet on the same layer 2 domain. Either have the existing gateway handle both subnets (with NAT if needed) or have a "router on a stick" (possibly with NAT) routing between the subnets x
2. Run multiple subnets on seperate VLANS over the existing physical infrastructure. Again you could either have the existing gateway router handle both VLANs or have a "router on a stick" (possiblly with NAT) has the advantage you can separate DHCP and broadcasts will stay constrained to the individual VLANs but the downside that the switches will need to support VLANs and be configured to put the correct port on the correct VLAN
3. Run the new devices on new physical infrastructure. Either have two seperate ports on the existing gateway router or have a router (possiblly with NAT) joining the existing and new networks.